# Is there a literal syntax for mutable collections?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, objective-c-literals

I know I can create an `NSArray` with `@[@"foo", @"bar"]` or an `NSDictionary` with `@{@0 : @"foo", @1 : @"bar"}`.

Is there a literal syntax for creating an `NSMutableArray` or an `NSMutableDictionary`?

Comment: Just don't forget that its `NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key" : @"value"};`, might be confusing with he way you have it written.  Different from `:objectsWithKeys`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. Just as how there isn't a syntax for creating an `NSMutableString` either. Mutable objects are not particularly suited to literal values.

Comment: Have to disagree with that last sentence. Programming in Python, for example, collections are created literally and mutable by default. It can be very handy.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Does python even have immutable collections?

Comment: Yes, there's things called ["tuples"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) which are immutable. `> (1, 2, 3)    # tuple (immutable array)` `> [1, 2, 3]    # list (mutable array)`

Comment: as posted below you do the following `NSMutableArray *list = [@[] mutableCopy];` i.e. you add mutableCopy at the end.
That is how the literal is specified

Comment: @maninvan That's not a literal. That's an expression that uses a literal.

Comment: You are correct in semantics. But from what happens from the programming perspective is that the expression is how you initialize a mutable object with some data in a short form syntax. The compiler will optimize this so it's probably reduced cpu instructions and memory copies. And it's less to write. It's more succinct. Which is what is desired. The answer 'no' is technically correct but not as helpful as showing the expression.

Comment: @maninvan No, the compiler does not optimize that. Obj-C does not *allow* the compiler to optimize that. It's required to construct an immutable array from the literal, and then invoke `mutableCopy` on the result. The expression `[@[] mutableCopy]` simply cannot be called a literal. Even if it was optimized, it's still not a literal.

Comment: @KevinBallard You are correct, but I get his point. Using literal syntax and adding mutableCopy to the end looks better than most alternatives and is easy to type. It's not an answer to OP's question, but it can be a solution to OP's problem.

Answer (score 105):

There isn't a built in way, but I just usually use `mutableCopy` like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [@[ @"1", @"2", @"3" ] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: This seems less efficient and not much shorter than `[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil]`.

Comment: Or alternatively: "NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[ @"1", @"2", @"3" ]];"  - though I like your example better  :)

Comment: There is a builtin way in [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16287860/1971013).

Comment: @meaning-matters that is definitely not a literal syntax.

Comment: Got to agree with @MattDiPasquale's comment; this is barely shorter than `NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:...`, is presumably less efficient for what little it matters, and - to my eye - slightly less readable too. A concise literal syntax would've been nice, but if this is the nearest thing to it, then I think I'll stick to the less hacky-feeling `arrayWithObjects` for initialising mutable arrays.

Comment: @MarkAmery How is that less hacky? The literal syntax expands to `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`, not `arrayWithObjects` so the literal syntax validates that all items are non-nil.

Comment: @danielbeard Creating an unnecessary intermediate object and then taking a copy of it just to save a few characters compared to directly creating the `NSMutableArray` with one of its own initialiser methods is what feels hacky to me.

Comment: As meaning-matters commented on his own NSJSONSerialization reply, mutableCopy only makes a shallow copy. That may be sufficient, but if not his NSJSONSerialization solution is the only general one so far.

Comment: You can also do `NSMutableArray *array = @[].mutableCopy;` which seems more readable.

Answer (score 18):

> But, is there a literal syntax for creating an NSMutableArray or an NSMutableDictionary?

No. Best alternative:

```
[@[ @"foo", @"bar"] mutableCopy]
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes. But not quite. Take a look at this;

`NSMutableArray *list = [@[] mutableCopy];`

This creates a non-mutable array `@[]` and calls `mutableCopy` which returns a `NSMutableArray *`. In place of `@[]`, you can give any array literal.

Comment: Do you know of any issues arising from using this in lieu of the longhand?

Comment: @JohnnyRockex there are no issues with this syntax, but it's pretty ugly if the array is empty to start with ;)

Comment: I love me some shorthand was just wondering if had a (technical) effect

Answer (score 3):

If you have a nested literal of arrays and dictionaries, you can turn this into a fully mutable version by going through `NSJSONSerialization`.  For example:

```
NSArray* array = @[ @{ @"call" : @{ @"devices" : @[ @"$(devices)" ] } } ];
NSData* data   = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array 
                                                 options:0 
                                                   error:nil];

NSJSONReadingOptions options = NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | 
                               NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves;
NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                               options:options
                                                                 error:nil];
```

It's a bit of a detour, but at least you don't have to write out the code yourself.  And the good thing is that `NSJSONSerialization` is very fast.

Comment: Uh dude, JSONKit is faster. By 5x. Plus, this is too circuitous. Just use -mutableCopy, then you can optionally use -autorelease.

Comment: @NathanielSymer Come on dude: The two year old [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) readme --well maintained stuff btw-- itself says it was just 25% - 40% faster.  And [`-mutableCopy` only does a shallow copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661770/does-mutablecopy-make-contained-objects-mutable).  The only way is to do something 'circuitous'.

Comment: you could also just do this: [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@"A",@"B"]]. sorry for the downvote, but serializing and deserializing is insane and won't work with many types of objects.

Comment: @kritzikratzi First, insane? You're taking a very simple example, not my example. Please write out `@[ @{ @"call" : @{ @"devices" : @[ @"$(devices)" ] } } ]` and you'll see how insane that is. Second, this works for the types given in @MattDiPasquale's and my example. Even more, I explicitly mention that this works for literals. So please don't apologise!