# Change value in this array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Was wondering how i would change the first value of "Jeremy Arimado" into a different string?

```
crewData = @[
                @{
                    @"roleNameAr": @"Jeremy Arimado",
                    @"rolePhoneAr":@"123456",
                    },
                @{
                    @"roleNameAr": @"Jeremy Arimado 2",
                    @"rolePhoneAr":@"123456",
                    },
                @{
                    @"roleNameAr": @"Jeremy Arimado 3",
                    @"rolePhoneAr":@"123456",
                    }
                ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@[]` literal produces an `NSArray` instance, which is immutable.
In the same way `@{}` produces an `NSDictionary`, immutable as well.

You have to obtain a mutable copy of the objects, before being able to modify it.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableCrewData = [crewData mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *mutableCrewMember = [mutableCrewData[0] mutableCopy];
mutableCrewMember[@"roleNameAr"] = @"Foo Bar";
mutableCrewData[0] = mutableCrewMember;
crewData = mutableCrewData;
```

An alternative would be to directly use `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSMutableArray`, but [you cannot directly use the literal syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416967/is-there-a-literal-syntax-for-mutable-collections) for that.